# Console shows [[Prototype]] and __proto__ in different positions

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I understand that `__proto__` is a getter for the value in the hidden property `[[Prototype]]` but the following screenshot in the Google Chrome console is a bit confusing for the following code:

```
function Person(name)
{
   this.name = name;
}

var newPerson = new Person("John")
console.log(newPerson);
```

[image]

[image]

I understand that I can call `newPerson.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__` and the prototype chain ends there at `null` but why is it shown differently in the console? To reach a `null` value in the chain in the console we have to click through `[[Prototype]].[[Prototype]].__proto__.[[Prototype]].__proto__.__proto__`. Hence, what does the above structure mean? and how are we able to call `newPerson.__proto__` when the first and only property is `[[Prototype]]`?